# How to reinstall 18.04 lts after 19.04 with many problems. Is installed beside windows

Tags: 19.04, reinstall

I tried to install 19.04 because of fractional scaling. 
During installation, there was an error
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1825420

After this, many small errors. update management cant make
a internet connection, my soundcard was not working, cant
copy from the desktop, folder wont open ...

I found this tutorial
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation

I try to download 
https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?country=DE&version=18.04.2&architecture=amd64
the stable version again to "Run the UbuntuInstaller". 
Directly in Disco, and it was mounted as new CD. 
I can open the cd, but I cant "run" the cd, or 
cant find the right information, how to do it.

This tutorial is different and not recommend...
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-downgrade-ubuntu-linux-system-to-its-previous-version

What can I do now? I also unsure, because I do have
a partial installation besides Windows and dont want 
to loose my files (if possible). With 18.04 everything
runs fine so far.

Thank you, Best Regards
Simon

Comment: Did you check Hashsums of downloaded files, maybe your download was already broken. Or your USB stick is. I'd try again from start verifying everything is fine. Ubuntu 19.04 shouldn't have these errors. And if you don't need LTS, I would really recommend 19.04 overy 18.04 which gnome version just does not feel ready ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like your system is really broken.

First of all, I recommend to try to start Ubuntu-Live-19.04 from an USB-Drive and then start the installation. If you haven't tried that before. (I'm not sure...) Just as in your second URL.

Otherwise, I recommend the following steps to downgrade:

1. Take an USB-Stick
2. Download the Ubuntu 18.04 ISO and put it on the stick
3. Start from the stick and during the installation try to Choose the Option Downgrade. (I believe it existed once, but I'm not sure if it's still) If it doesn't exist you can choose: Erase Ubuntu 19.04...

But don't forget to save all your data off the Ubuntu-Installation to an external drive. And as long as you don't make any errors, your Windows-Installation shouldn't be affected. From my own experience, I can say: Unfortunately errors happen too much.

A Downgrade is really risky and should only be made if there is no other option.

Comment: thank you for the quick and detailed answer!